# ruby 1.8 has find function, however after 1.9 there is not

Tags: ruby

In ruby1.8, `String` class has methods like `find` and `find_all`. The `find` usage is like following:

#### test.rb

```
a="123 123\n234 234\n456 456"
b = a.find { |ln| a.split[0] == ARGV[0] }
print b
```

I can get the following result:

```
# ./test.rb 123
123 123
```

However, after ruby 1.9, it fails because there is no `find` for the `String` instance. I need to handle these scripts. And I prefer to use the latest stable ruby.

I don't know if I can add a customized method for `find` and `find_all`, and how. I thought I can open `String` class, and add `find` method. However, I don't know how to receive the block as arguments, e.g., `{ |ln| a.split[0] == ARGV[0] }`. Does anyone know any solutions?

Comment: Why there's `{|ln| a.split[0] == xxx}`, not `{|ln| ln.split[0] == xxx}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-each_line) which turns the list into an array of strings, and use `Array`'s [`find`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-find) to do the job

```
b = a.each_line.find { |ln| ln.split[0] == ARGV[0] }
# => "123 123\n"
```

---

If you want to patch `String` itself, you could create a delegation method in `String`.

```
class String
  def find(*args, &block)
    each_line.find(*args, &block)
  end
end
```

now you should be able to keep your old code, and it should work.

Comment: I think you carried over a mistake in the question: should be `ln.split..`. Also, maybe the enumerator `each_line` would be better than `lines`, as it would use less memory.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks. That works. But can add "find" method into String class? Anyway, there are lots of lines of code need to be modified if I use "lines" or "each_line". If the "find" or "find_all" can be added, it is most convenient.

Comment: @user3932144 added a method to patch the `String` class.

Comment: Uri, I've got an upvote ready to go, as soon as you fix that wee mistake. I'll check back in the morning.

Comment: Thank you. @Uri. It is what I want. However, your example code can not work for me. Because when I see the &block, I think it translate as the whole line. I.E., block.source is `"b = a.find { |ln| a.split[0] == ARGV[0] }"`. But what I think it need only part of the code like, `each_line.find(|ln| a.split[0] == ARGV[0])`.  How to make it work?

Comment: @user3932144 - I'm not sure I understand your remark, my code should work, `b = a.find { |ln| a.split[0] == ARGV[0] }` will work just fine

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add return. Use your example code, I run following test script `#!/usr/bin/env ruby

$LOAD_PATH.push('.')
require 'cc'
a = "123\n234\n345"
aaa = a.find {|ln| ln == "234"}
puts "result: #{aaa}\n"`. And I find aaa is nil. and the result expects to be "234"

Comment: @user3932144 the lines returned contain the trailing new line (`"\n"`). Try either `aaa = a.find {|ln| ln == "234\n"}` or `aaa = a.find {|ln| ln.chomp == "234"}`

Comment: @UriAgassi. No, it can not work. Still return nil. I think in `each_line.find(*args, &block)`. Since the block in "find" method is "aaa = a.find {|ln| ln == '234\n'}", hence, the each_line.find statement is equal to `aaa = a.each_line.find(|ln| ln == '234')`. However, inside "find" method, there is no "aaa" variable...

Comment: @zhaox11 - I have run both lines as I printed them, and they worked fine. Could you put your code in http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: Oh, sorry. It does work! I found it was failed because I add "binding.pry" within "find" function. After remove it, it works. Thank you, @UriAgassi!